# javascript convert object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js, javascript-objects

I am trying to build a d3.js heatmap from a CSV dataset. Upon import using d3.csv, the data looks like this:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, columns: Array(11)]
```

where each object is as follows:

```
Object {0: "0.934999642", 1: "0.1031451091", 2: "0.077435557", 3: 
"0.129644215", 4: "0.666245944", 5: "0.133087829", 6: "0.113218775", 7: 
"0.120796943", 8: "0.257501418", 9: "0.840916491", "": "0"}
```

I have been trying to use the data as is, but for loops are too slow (the real dataset has 1300 values), and attempting a nesting structure doesn't work because d3's data() function can only take an array.

Like so:

```
var row =  svg.selectAll(".rows")
                     .data(data)
                     .enter()
                     .append("rect")
                     [etc]

d3.selectAll(".blocks")//nested data
                     .data(function(d) {//d has no length property, so this line fails
                        return d;
                     })
                     .enter()
                     .append("rect")
                    [etc]
```

How can I convert the array of objects into an array of arrays? Alternatively, is there a way to use the array of objects successfully? Also, is there any reason why it isn't coming directly from the CSV in an array of arrays rather than this weird object array? The data was curated in and exported from Python's Pandas, if that makes a difference, and we can make adjustments there.

Thank you.

Comment: This is clearly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking what you are asking right now, please explain exatcly what you want to draw with that data. Besides that, the answer to *"is there any reason why it isn't coming directly from the CSV in an array of arrays rather than this weird object array?"* is yes, that's precisely what `d3.csv` does.

Comment: I am trying to build a d3.js heatmap from a CSV dataset. How do I do this given the dataset I am working with?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the CSV import issue. Because of how the dataset was curated, I have been trying to figure out if there was a problem on that end that was resulting in an unexpected d3.csv import structure. It is good to know that this data structure is what is expected.

Comment: I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489042/1175714), but I encourage you to look around for similar questions before posting one. This will probably be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: is your problem only one of speed?

Comment: Well, I see you have 4 answers so far, and they are all valid, because they answer your *actual question*. However, since you told that you want to create a heatmap, I predict that none of them will help you. To avoid the XY problem, post a question clearly showing your data structure, your enter selections and explaining what you want to achieve. Preferably, a **new** question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is straightforward enough with a functional style using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control):

```
let myArray = Object
    .keys(myObj)
    .map(key => myObj[key]);
```

Though you may want to guarantee that the keys appear in order and exclude non-numeric keys.

```
let myArray = Object
    .keys(myObj)
    .sort((a,b) => +a - +b)
    .filter(key => !isNaN(+key))
    .map(key => myObj[key]);
```

You can in-turn use this with map to apply it to the parent array

```
let newArray = bigArray
    .map(el => Object
        .keys(el)
        /* ... */
        .map(key => el[key]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the Array and map each object to the Object values:

```
var result=array.map(Object.values)
```

But its the same speed as two loops.

Comment: You need to make it clearer that `array` refers to the data structure in OP's example. I almost downvoted your answer with a lecture on "why this answer is incorrect" as a result of the lack of information, because I thought you were trying to call `Array.map` with a function as its input and somehow magically get the wanted data. Unclear intent is a good way to fail a code review.

Comment: @braden best i admit that i left away the explanantion. However, thats still no reason to downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but -- *what's* no reason to downvote? I *almost* downvoted this answer for being incorrect (and that is the only reason I will downvote an answer), not for ambiguity. But I am thorough, and didn't end up downvoting because I was eventually able to verify that your answer was correct. I make great effort to avoid erroneously downvoting an answer.

Comment: @braden best ive never downvoted an answer. If its unhelpful / wrong i comment and explain why i think its wrong, if its impossible to reach the answerer i usually edit myself / flag. Thats the helpfullwst for all...

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't think I've ever downvoted an answer, either. So I guess that makes me a hypocrite for singling you out. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

An Array of Arrays. Using a While loop with object iteration and array assignment. Technically two loops.Practically should be counted as one because it is a continuation of a nested count.

```js
var objs = [{
  0: "0.934999642",
  1: "0.1031451091",
  2: "0.077435557",
  3: "0.129644215",
  4: "0.666245944",
  5: "0.133087829",
  6: "0.113218775",
  7: "0.120796943",
  8: "0.257501418",
  9: "0.840916491",
  "": "0"
}, {
  0: "0.934999642",
  1: "0.1031451091",
  2: "0.077435557",
  3: "0.129644215",
  4: "0.666245944",
  5: "0.133087829",
  6: "0.113218775",
  7: "0.120796943",
  8: "0.257501418",
  9: "0.840916491",
  "": "0"
}]

var i = objs.length,
  arr = Array.from(new Array(i), x => []);
while (i--) {
  for (let val in objs[i]) {
    var values = objs[i][val];
    arr[i].push([values]);
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Your solution seems awful complicated, and includes a `for..in` loop, which is a statement that should be avoided altogether. Use `Object.keys` instead. `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){ ... })` is cleaner and more predictable.

Comment: a while loop is complicated? What reason is there to avoid the "for in loop" in this instance? Object.keys is good shorthand and similarly so for forEach, However, the question was one of performance, and you sacrifice that with the shorthand you have selected.

Comment: Sounds like [Premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) to me. You should be optimizing where big gains can be made, and only after you have a functioning product. Apply the 80:20 rule and don't needlessly peck away at code that will only net you diminishing returns. Otherwise you end up with an unmaintainable mess. Plus, if you're really worried about squeezing out every possible ounce of performance, we have `asm.js`, which you can target with a compiler for another language, which will be far more optimized than anything a human can do.

Comment: You think it's "premature" to assume he is dealing with large data when he says he is dealing with mapping large amounts of data from "CSV" files. Maybe when he mentions "for loops are too slow". I don't know, maybe he needs something even slower... I don't know... Maybe a suboptimal approach and obfuscation are exactly what this questioner is really asking for. In which case you have him covered   :-)

Comment: Unless you think minifiers and compilers that target asm.js are somehow "obfuscation" (which is a ludicrous viewpoint in itself), I have no idea where you got the idea that I'm obfuscating. Code should be clean and maintainable first. And when you're optimizing, you should aim for opportunities to save seconds, not *microseconds*. Again, 80:20 rule. 80% of your optimizations will affect 20% of the code; the rest is not worth the bother and you'll be beaten out by automated tools every time. If you really think your "optimizations" are effective, I'd like to see some benchmarks to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

myObj = {prop1:[object, object,...], prop2: ''} ;

to get prop1 as array, use this:

var result = myObj.prop1;

or
result = myObj.prop1.map(function (item) { 
/*item - your each object, you can  get any property, like: return {"name": item. name, "value" : item[3];} ;*/
return item;}) ;

result = [{name: Alex, value: Cash},..] ;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to properly format your answers in the future, as well as the [help page on answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) to get a better idea of how to write a good answer. Your answer in its current state is very low quality and is bound to get downvoted into oblivion. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You already have 4 different answers showing you how to convert an object with several properties in an array. However, as I said in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487616/javascript-convert-object-to-an-array#comment75969585_44487616), this seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, since what you really want at the end is just creating a heatmap.

Of course you can use any of the provided answers to create your data array in your inner selection. However, there are different ways to achieve the same result. This answer is just my two cents regarding your **objective**, not regarding what you actually asked.

You are correct when you said that `data()` doesn't accept an object. In fact, `data()` only accepts three things:

1. An array;
2. A function;
3. Nothing.

That being said, we have to somehow convert that huge object in several objects, since each individual object represents a data point.

#### Preparing your data array

Suppose you have the following CSV (an 8 x 8 matrix of values). In this CSV, the first row, the *header*, is just the column number. All the values (from the second row on) go from 0 to 100:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
99, 01, 01, 56, 65, 34, 87, 65
76, 99, 73, 23, 54, 62, 12, 15
54, 77, 66, 23, 98, 76, 11, 12
13, 24, 56, 76, 88, 75, 43, 76
12, 33, 44, 52, 45, 87, 65, 67
88, 76, 67, 87, 54, 34, 44, 45
12, 13, 24, 65, 45, 47, 76, 87
65, 43, 23, 42, 42, 34, 42, 17
```

With this CSV, you can create a data array in which each object contains the row number, the column number and the value. For instance, parsing the CSV to an array named `rawData`, we can populate the final data array, named `data`, like this:

```
rawData.forEach(function(d, i) {
    Object.keys(d).forEach(function(e) {
        data.push({
            row: i,
            column: e,
            value: d[e]
        })
    })
});
```

Thus, you only need to access `d.row`, `d.column` and `d.value` in your selection.

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.column)
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.row)
})
.attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.value)
})
```

Here is a very simple demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var rawData = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text())
var color = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range(["maroon", "lawngreen"]);
var xScale = d3.scaleBand().domain(d3.range(1, 9, 1)).range([20, 180]);
var yScale = d3.scaleBand().domain(d3.range(1, 9, 1)).range([20, 180]);

var data = [];

rawData.forEach(function(d, i) {
  Object.keys(d).forEach(function(e) {
    data.push({
      row: i,
      column: e,
      value: d[e]
    })
  })
});

var rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth() - 2)
  .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth() - 2)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.column)
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.row)
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.value)
  })
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="200"></svg>
<pre id="csv">1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
99,01,01,56,65,34,87,65
76,99,73,23,54,62,12,15
54,77,66,23,98,76,11,12
13,24,56,76,88,75,43,76
12,33,44,52,45,87,65,67
88,76,67,87,54,34,44,45
12,13,24,65,45,47,76,87
65,43,23,42,42,34,42,17</pre>
```

Note that in this demo I'm using a `<pre>` element to store the data, since I cannot use `d3.csv` in a Stack snippet.